# Apache Storm: How to micro batch events from Kafka Spout

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

How can i micro batch events in kafka spout to reduce IO calls in the bolts that follow?
The expectation is: emit a batch of maximum size 100 using events in kafka but wait maximum of 1 second to form this batch. If there are not enough events within 1 second, emit the available events.

I can achieve the same in Akka by "source.groupedWithin" method. How do i do the same with kafka spout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Chris' answer, you can also use Storm's windowing feature https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0/Windowing.html. You can find an example of this at https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/examples/storm-starter/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/starter/SlidingWindowTopology.java

You can alternatively use Trident for this if you like. Once you've set up a `KafkaTridentSpoutOpaque`, you can use the Kafka client settings to control how many messages are in each batch. You would use the `KafkaSpoutConfig` `pollTimeoutMs` to set how long you want to wait for a batch to fill, and set the `max.poll.records` Kafka client configuration via `KafkaSpoutConfig.Builder.setProp` to control the max number of records in a batch.

For a complete example of using the Kafka Trident spout, see https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/examples/storm-kafka-client-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/kafka/trident/TridentKafkaClientTopologyNamedTopics.java

Answer (score 2):

Look at Storm's tick tuples which provide a way to send scheduled tuples (ticks) to your bolts.  For your case you can configure a tick every second.  The bolt, meanwhile, would simply process tuples from the Kafka spout and batch them, sending a batch on when it reaches 100 messages (in your case) or when you get a tick tuple.  Note that you do need to check each input tuple to see whether it's a tick or a Kafka message.